# Java Netbeans no crea carpeta Dist

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un problema desde que instalé Java Netbeans, y aún no encuentro solución. Al darle "Clean and Build" a un proyecto que cree (una calculadora simple) no encuentro la carpeta "dist". Que por lo que he escuchado es la necesaria para utilizar mi aplicación fuera de la interfaz Netbeans.
He intentado lo mismo con otros proyectos pero en ninguno se genera la carpeta Dist.
Tengo Java Netbeans 12.2
Maven 3.6.3
Jdk-15.0.1

Mi pom es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguno tiene idea de cuál puede ser la solución a mi error? Si es necesario brindaré cualquier dato que soliciten. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿En la pestaña de files, al lado de la de projects (zona izquierda en predeterminado) no te aparece? En teoría con hacer Clean Build te lo genera.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, para futuras preguntas pon el código como texto, no como captura de pantalla, es mucho más legible. En este caso, recuerda que Maven guarda todo lo generado en una carpeta *target*, lo más probable es que Netbeans simplemente ejecute Maven o replique su funcionamiento. Eclipse también genera la carpeta target en proyectos generados desde un pom.

Comment: @iCodeForCaffeine Lamentablemente no, también tenía la idea de que al hacer "clean and build" se iba a generar. De todas maneras muchas gracias por su comentario.

Comment: @SJuan76 Lo siento, si realizo otra pregunta tomaré sus consejos. ¿Entonces si utilizo Maven es normal que al ejercer el "Clean And Build" no se genere la carpeta Dist? ¿Cómo podría hacer para poder crear la carpeta Dist o distribuir mi aplicación hacia otros ordenadores? ¡Muchas gracias por su respuesta!

Comment: @SJuan76 Por cierto, para aclarar, en la carpeta Target se genera el siguiente archivo: nombredelproyecto-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Comment: Bueno, pues eso son las clases compiladas. Si quieres cambiar el directorio, configura el plugin de maven (hay montones de tutoriales), pero maven se basa en seguir la convención y no cambiar el comportamiento si no es necesario. ¿Por que necesitas la carpeta "dist" y no te va bien que el jar te lo monte en "target"?

Comment: @SJuan76 Te refieres al jar (nombredelproyecto-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)? Por alguna razón no me deja ejecutarlo, siempre atribuí ese problema a que era necesario que el jar esté en la carpeta "dist".

Comment: Describe en la pregunta lo que haces para ejecutarlo y qué es lo que pasa. Pero sea lo que sea, no tiene nada que ver con la carpeta.

Comment: @SJuan76 Ahh ok. ¡Muchas gracias por la información! Entonces, para transferir mi programa a otro computador, ¿debería copiar y pegar solo el .jar o toda la carpeta target? Lo siento por mi ingnorancia, aún soy muy novato en esto y realmente agradezco la ayuda.